# Word Window Type mismatch

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to capture pages in word as image and paste in Excel via VBA, below is the complete code. but got a `Type Mismatch` error as the comment in below. How to fix the error?

```
Function openFile() As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Add "Word Files", "*.doc*", 1
        .Show
        openFile = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    End With
End Function

Function readWord(ByVal path As String)
    Debug.Print "Read word", path
    
    Set objWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objWordDoc = objWordApp.Documents.Open(path)
    
    objWordApp.Visible = False

    Dim objPage As Page
    Dim objPane As Pane
    Dim objWindow As Window
    
    Debug.Print objWordDoc.Windows.Count
    Debug.Print TypeName(objWordDoc.Windows.Item(1))
     
    For Each objWindow In objWordDoc.Windows 'Got Type mismatch Here
        For Each objPane In objWindow.Panes
            For Each objPage In objPane.Pages
                Debug.Print "Page"
            Next objPage
        Next objPane
    Next objWindow
    
End Function

Sub processWord()
    Dim p As String
    p = openFile()
    readWord (p)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused because your code contains a confused mess of objects.

You are attempting to use late binding for Word and yet you declare:

```
Dim objPage As Page
Dim objPane As Pane
Dim objWindow As Window
```

As you appear to be writing your code in Excel this results in these objects being:

```
Dim objPage As Excel.Page
Dim objPane As Excel.Pane
Dim objWindow As Excel.Window
```

This causes the type mismatch error.

I suggest that you avoid using late binding until you have your code fully working. Then you can change all the object declarations to `As Object`, if you really feel it is necessary.

Incidentally, if you are thinking that you can use the SaveAsPNG method listed in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.page#methods) to get images of the documents pages, you can't - it doesn't exist.

Comment: LOL! `you can't - it doesn't exist.` sad news to me!